# Unit testing for Yii modules

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii

I wish to do unit testing for Yii modules separately. I have configured it successfully. But when I run the test class for my module controller(LeadController) following error occurs.

```
PHPUnit 3.7.31 by Sebastian Bergmann.
```

> Configuration read from
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\AdlugeCore\protected\modules\lead\tests\ phpunit.xml
>
> E
>
> Time: 153 ms, Memory: 3.00Mb
>
> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) LeadTest::testActionAdd Trying to get property of non-object
>
> D:\xampp\htdocs\AdlugeCore\protected\modules\lead\controllers\LeadController.php
>   :57
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\AdlugeCore\protected\modules\lead\tests\unit\LeadTest.php:15
>
> FAILURES! Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.

Below is my test class:

```
Yii::import('application.protected.modules.lead.controllers.*');
Yii::import('application.protected.modules.lead.components.*');

class LeadTest extends CTestCase {

    public $obj;

    public function setUp() {
        $this->obj = new LeadController(rand());
        $this->obj->init();
    } 

    public function testActionAdd() {
        $this->obj->actionAdd();
        $this->assertTrue(TRUE);
    }
    public function tearDown() {
        unset($this->obj);
    }
}
```

In LeadController.php

```
class LeadController extends Controller {

    public $lead;

    public function init() {

        $this->lead = new LeadManager();
    }

    public function actionAdd($param = array()) {

        $result = $this->lead->AddProcess($param);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue...

Comment: The error is on line 57 of `D:\xampp\htdocs\AdlugeCore\protected\modules\lead\controllers\LeadController.php` so could you add that?

Comment: $result = $this->lead->AddProcess($param); 
it is given above...

Comment: Could you `var_dump($this->lead)` before `$result = $this->lead->AddProcess($param);`?

Comment: You better create separate tests for the `LeadManager` and `LeadController`. 
In the `LeadController` in the normal case the framework triggers `CController::run($actionID)` method, so if you want to test the real routing this is the way, not by calling the `actionAdd` method directly.

Comment: I got answer from here http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/52969-unit-testing-for-yii-modules/page__p__244356__fromsearch__1#entry244356

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is that method init() is never called while doing the unit test.
If you put the piece of code you have there in the __construct() method you'll be fine.